# Access second to last element of array

Tags: vector, julia, dynamic-arrays

I know I can access the last element of an array with

`array[end]`

I've tried to access the second to last element with

`array[end-1]` which (unsurprisingly) did not work. I was unable to find anything reading through the documentation or just through googling. How do I access the second to last element? Thanks for any help you can provide.

### Edit

It turns out that what I thought was an array was actually a vector. In that case, `vector[end - 1]` does not work, but that which is suggested below does.

Comment: `end-1` *should* work. Do have example code?

Comment: I tested it, and it does in fact work. It should work for all collections that have a size, including all `AbstractArray`s of all dimensions, tuples, strings, etc.

Comment: @DNF, That's funny. I have no idea why it didn't work. I was able to figure out `size(arr)[1] - 1` to get the index.

Comment: Why there is not example code for this question?

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel Example code is not required. I showed what I attempted. I showed my rationale for doing so. I explained that I looked through the docs. Especially for a task this trivial, example code is not necessary.

Comment: `[1,2,3,4][end-1]` works so for sure normally you can write `array[end-1]` and it just works everywhere in Julia as long as something is an array (see @DNF comments). Hence, most likely your `array` variable is not an array.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel The workaround below works so I didn't think too much of it. I just looked at the code closer and you're right. It's a vector. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: `end-1` *definitely* 100% guaranteed also works for vectors, since vectors are arrays. Example code *is* required here.

Comment: @DNF Thinking back, it was probably just a typographic error. I will attempt to close this post.

Comment: The confusion seen in connection with this question demonstrates why it is vital to *always* include a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example There is virtually never any question too trivial to benefit from example code. Especially if it gets to the point where other posters are asking for code, it is certainly needed.

Comment: @DNF, Yeah. I totally thought it was reproducible. I thought this was just a basic "why can't I find this in the docs" thing. I did not realize this was unique to me. Sorry. I'll try to replicate the problem based off of only the code I provide next time. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: No, it's totally understandable you didn't include code at first, when asking the question, since it really was that simple. I actually meant after people started responding that it *should* work, and requested a code example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also surprised that doesn't work. Are you sure you tried it on an array with at least two elements?

You could also try using the `length()` function:

```
last = array[length(array)]
secondToLast = array[length(array)-1]
```

Comment: You're off by one, it should be `last = array[length(array)]` and `secondToLast = array[length(array)-1]`. You're using 0-based indexing, while Julia is 1-based.

Comment: Whoops. Nice catch.

Comment: What's the difference between `size` and `length`?

Comment: `length` is the number of elements in an array, `size` is the shape. So a 3x4 matrix has `length` 12, and `size` (3,4). You can get just one of them with `size(arr, 1)` or `size(arr, 2)`-

Comment: No clue. I quickly scrolled through https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/julia/ to find the `length()` function. Didn't happen upon a `size()` function.